# AppState removeEventListener not removing listener

Tags: react-native

Simple code:

```
useEffect(() => {

        AppState.addEventListener("change", handleChangeEvent);

        return (() => {
            console.log("REMOVING EVENT LISTENER");
            AppState.removeEventListener("change", handleChangeEvent);
        });
    }, []);

    const handleChangeEvent = () => {
        console.log("EVENT LISTENER FIRING");
    };
```

Navigate to new screen:

```
const changeScreen = () => {
        return props.navigation.navigate("MainView", {})
    }
```

**When arriving at new screen:** The `REMOVING EVENT LISTENER` fires. But in this new screen, the event listener is still listening.

Why is it not being removed?

Answer (score 0):

try using useFocussedEffect instead,

```
useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            AppState.addEventListener("change", handleChangeEvent);
            return () => {
                AppState.removeEventListener("change", handleChangeEvent);
            }
        }, [])
);
```